# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n^{1/n}}}{e^{n(n^{1/n}-1)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n^{1/n}}}{e^{n(n^{1/n}-1)}}$.

My try: The numerator can be written as: $e^{n^{1/n}\ln n}$, so we get:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}(n^{1/n}\ln n-n(n^{1/n}-1))}$$

Now its enough to find the limit in power as:

$$P=\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}\:\ln n-n(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$$

Letting $n=\frac{1}{y}$ we get:

$$P=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{-y\ln y-1+y^{\frac{1}{y}}}{y^{1+\frac{1}{y}}}$$

Which is in $0/0$ form

Using L'Hopital's Rule its too complicated. any way to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have$$P=\lim_{y\to0^+}p(y),\,p(y):=\frac{-y\ln y-1+y^{y}}{y^{1+y}}.$$As $y\to0^+$, $y\ln y\to0$ and $y^y=\exp(y\ln y)=1+y\ln y+\frac12y^2\ln^2y+o(y^2\ln^2y)$, so the numerator $\sim\frac12y^2\ln^2y$ and $p\sim\frac12y^{1-y}\ln^2y$. Since $y^\epsilon\ln y=\frac{1}{\epsilon}y^\epsilon\ln(y^\epsilon)\in o(1)$ for all $\epsilon>0$, $P=0$ so $L=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
n^{1/n}=\exp\left(\frac1n\log n\right)
$$
Now
$$
\xi(n):=\frac1n\log n\to0,\;\;n\to+\infty
$$
and
$$
e^{\xi}-1=\xi+o(\xi),\;\;\xi\to0
$$
thus
$$
n(n^{1/n}-1)=n\left(\xi(n)+o(\xi(n))\right)=\log n+\underbrace{no(1/n\log n)}_{\to0}\to+\infty
$$
as $n\to+\infty$.

Thus your denominator goes as $n$, likewise your numerator. Your limit is 1.

Comment: I'm unsure about your last step. I agree that $\frac{e^\xi-\xi-1}{\xi}\to 0$ which is the same as $\frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)-\log n}{\log n}\to 0$. I don't see how it follows that $n(n^{1/n}-1)-\log n\to 0$ from there, which we want for the denominator to be $\sim n$. What am I missing?

Comment: The denominator is $e^{n(n^{1/n}-1)}=e^{\log n + o(1/n\log n)}\sim n$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem that you read my comment. I asked you where does it follow from that $n(n^{1/n}-1) = \log n + o(1/n\log n)$? What you wrote looks like you are using $no(f(n)) = o(f(n))$, which is not true.

Comment: You're right. I just took care of the fact the second summand would have vanished. I edited